# Plesk - Add new domain to new dedicated server

Tags: domains, dns, plesk, dedicated-hosting, windows-server-2008

I have just get a new dedicated server running on Windows Server 2008 with Parallels Plesk 12 installed. It is my very first time deal with dedicated server. So, how can I add a new purchased domain name and make it work with my dedicated server?

Answer (score 1):

Check it out :

https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/710/Add+or+Delete+Domains+and+Domain+Aliases+in+Plesk#dv_managed

Or you can add domain name via this method :

To Add New Domain Names to Plesk

Log in to Plesk

Click Add New Domain.

Complete the following, and then click OK:

Section What to do...

Domain name Enter the domain name you want to use.

DNS Settings    Select the DNS option you want to use for the domain name.

Hosting type    Select the type of hosting you want to create. If you want to host a website for this domain, select Website hosting.

Hosting settings

Enter the directory you want to use as the new site's root directory, i.e.

the directory that displays when visitors go to the domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is how can I add new purchased domain to my hosting. For example, I buy a new domain at somewhere, and I can add new domain in plesk on my dedicated server. But how can I have that domain link to my server?

Comment: do you know name server configuration ?

Comment: Don't know. All I know when using shared hosting, when I buy a new domain, I just need to put the hosting DNS on the domain setting and add that domain on the hosting control panel and it will works.

Comment: Search google for create name server.

Select one of existing domain for using name server, for example select : yourmaindomain.com

Add new ns (nameserver) for yourmaindomain.com in your domain panel (where you bought domain) and point to your server ip.

And then change new purchased domain dns to ns1.yourmaindomain.com  thats all.